# read each line in a file, subsitute variables and send output to file bash

Tags: bash, variables, loops, while-loop, cat

i have a file containing certain variables. i'd like to read each line, substitute the variables and echo the output. the source file i'd like to read is something like:

```
VAR1 is $A
VAR2 is $B
VAR3 is $C
```

i tried the script below but the output is just the same.

```
#/bin/sh
A=1
B=2
C=3

cat $file | while read LINE
do
 echo $LINE
done
```

how do i make it replace the variables to get this output?

```
VAR1 is 1
VAR2 is 2
VAR3 is 3
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
echo $LINE
```

Put:

```
eval echo $LINE
```

Answer (score 1):

`eval` will execute any valid shell code, so it is a bit of a security risk. Here's a more focused solution that *only* does parameter expansion, without the risk of arbitrary code execution.

```
#/bin/sh
A=1
B=2
C=3

# Break each line into the variable name, "is", and the value. Then
# strip the leading dollar sign from the value to keep just the
# parameter name. Finally, use indirect parameter expansion to print
# the value.
while read name _ value
do
 value=${value#$}
 echo "$name is ${!value}"
done < "$file"
```

Comment: this indeed is good to know! although the files i'll be reading won't contain any shell code, i'm keen on trying this out. problem is, the lines will have varying length and so will the position of each variable(s) along the line. any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Hm, that's trickier. You'd have to go through the line word by word, looking for words that start with `$` (assuming you don't have anything like `foo${bar}baz`), and do the replacement if necessary before echoing. I don't often say this, but use `eval` as long as you are aware of the risks.

Answer (score 0):

As eval is a security risk,
why not try :-

```
cat $file | while read LINE
do
   echo $LINE | sed -e "s/\$A/$A/g" -e "s/\$B/$B/g" -e "s/\$C/$C/g"
done
```

Or simply :-

```
sed -e "s/\$A/$A/g" -e "s/\$B/$B/g" -e "s/\$C/$C/g" $file
```